# REGEX - Capture anything until first space or first number

Tags: regex

I need to parse the product names and get only the first part until space or number, whichever comes first.

For e.g.,

```
Product Name        | Expected Output
SEROFLO250 INHALER  | SEROFLO
SEROFLO INHALER     | SEROFLO
SEROFLO 250 INHALER | SEROFLO
```

I can only parse until the first space with `([^\s]+)`. How can I parse until the first space or number, whichever comes first?

Comment: Just use `^[A-Za-z]+` then. Or `^[^\d\s]+`.

Answer (score 3):

You're nearly there, the `[^]` can contain multiple tokens that are treated as an *or* so `[^\s\d]` will match any character that isn't as space *or* digit. Also as you only want the text at the start of the line add `^` to the start; `^` is the *start of string anchor*, if multi-line mode is enabled then it's the start of a line, otherwise it's the start of the whole string.

Combining these you get `^([^\s\d]+)`